# If Column Contains String then enter value for that row

Tags: r, string

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
A     B
ABC1  0
DEF2  4
DEG0  4
```

How do I transform this so that if a row contains the letter "D" then insert the value "yes" in a new column and "no" if not.

Final dataframe should look like this:

```
A     B    C
ABC1  0    no
DEF2  4    yes
DEG0  4    yes
```

Comment: Try `ifelse(grepl("D", df$A), "yes", "no")`

Comment: good succinct question. Should not have been downvoted

Answer (score 34, accepted):

We can use `grepl` to return a logical index by matching the 'D' in the 'A' column, and then with `ifelse`, change the logical vector to 'yes' and 'no'

```
df$C <- ifelse(grepl("D", df$A), "yes", "no")
```

Comment: is there dplyr way to achieve the same with mutate ?

Comment: @user5249203 it would be `library(dplyr);library(stringr);df <- df %>% mutate(C = case_when(str_detect(A, "D") ~ "yes", TRUE ~ "no"))`