# Checking if phrase contains a certain word

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a column containing random names. I would like to create a code that would create another column (using mutate function) that would check if the name contains the word "Mr." which would result to the new column generating "Male"

Comment: Try `df %>% mutate(newCol = ifelse(grepl("Mr\\.", othercol), "Male", othercol))`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19747384/how-to-create-new-column-in-dataframe-based-on-partial-string-matching-other-col

Comment: This is a basic question, please read [some manuals](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info)

Comment: [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903376/if-column-contains-string-then-enter-value-for-that-row), but without `dplyr::mutate`.

Answer (score 1):

using dplyr and stringr:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

df <- data.frame(name = c("Mr. Robinson", "Mrs. robinson", "Gandalf","asdMr.dfa"))

df <- df %>% mutate(male = ifelse(str_detect(df$name, fixed("Mr.")), TRUE, FALSE))
```

Output:

```
> df
           name  male
1  Mr. Robinson  TRUE
2 Mrs. robinson FALSE
3       Gandalf FALSE
4     asdMr.dfa  TRUE
```

Be aware that this matches the Phrase "Mr." anywhere in the string, not just the beginning. If you don't want that I'd use regular expressions:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(male = ifelse(str_detect(name, "^Mr\\."), TRUE, FALSE))
> df
           name  male
1  Mr. Robinson  TRUE
2 Mrs. robinson FALSE
3       Gandalf FALSE
4     asdMr.dfa FALSE
```

This could also be achieved without the stringr package: (inspired by @akrun)

```
df <- df %>% mutate(male = ifelse(grepl("^Mr\\.", name), TRUE, FALSE))
```

#### EDIT:

@docendo discimus pointed out that the `ifelse()` isn't necessary since we're creating a logical-column and that's exactly what grepl returns. So:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(male = grepl("^Mr\\.", name))
```

Without dplyr:

```
df <- transform(df, male = grepl("^Mr\\.", name))
```

Comment: If you just return a logical true/false you don't need the `ifelse` since that's what `grepl` returns anyway. For that matter, you don't need dplyr either. It could simply be `transform(df, male = grepl("^Mr\\.", name))`

Comment: hey cool, i didn't know that! makes perfect sense though, thanks