# If any row contains a substring, then flag

Tags: r

I have a dataset of character variables:

```
col1 = c("a","b","c")
col2 = c("a","b_a","d")
df = data.frame(col1,col2)

  col1 col2
1    a    a
2    b  b_a
3    c    d
```

I want to create a variable a that flags 1,0 if any value in that row contains the substring "a".

```
  col1 col2 a
1    a    a 1
2    b  b_a 1
3    c    d 0
```

My attempt is below. It doesn't quite do it, as I believe it takes `TRUE` if any value in the dataframe contains the substring, rather than the row.

```
df["a"] = ifelse(any(sapply(df,function(x) str_detect(x,"a")),TRUE),1,0)
```

My thinking was that with an `ifelse` statement, any functions within the `ifelse` statement only evaluates `df[i,]` rather than the entire dataframe where `i` is the row it is looking at. This doesn't seem to be the case.

1. How do I construct the data frame I'm looking for? Note that in my real dataset, there are 100+ columns, so it doesn't make sense to list them all out.
2. Why doesn't ifelse only evaluate row `i` of `df`, rather than the whole `df`?

Note that previous questions only look [at one variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903376/if-column-contains-string-then-enter-value-for-that-row), I am looking at all variables so this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @A.Suliman I don't think so. The post you referenced only searches on 1 variable. I am looking for all variables in the row. In the example I've posted, I am doing a substring search of col1 and col2. Plus, I am looking for help understanding the underlying logic of ifelse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
grepl('a', paste0(df$col1, df$col2))
```

Or to generalise for any number of columns

```
grepl('a',  do.call(paste0, df))
```

And a third option, which may be safer if you are searching for multi-character substrings, rather than single letters.  In this case you may want to avoid using `paste` so that e.g. searching for `'ab'` in the vector `c('xa', 'bx')` does not give a false positive.  In this situation, we can use:

```
substr = 'a'
as.logical(colSums(apply (df, 1, function(x) grepl(substr, x))))
```

Comment: This yields a logical vector. Wrap it in a call to `as.numeric` to yield zeroes and ones.

Comment: An alternative to `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` in your second  approach would be `do.call(paste0, df)`. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 1):

**1) How do I construct the data frame I'm looking for?**

```
df$a <- apply(df,1,function(x) { 
  as.numeric( length(grep("a",x)) > 0) 
  })
```

**Output**

```
  col1 col2 a
1    a    a 1
2    b  b_a 1
3    c    d 0
```

**2) Why doesn't ifelse only evaluate row i of df, rather than the whole df?**

Let's break it down -

1. You are doing `sapply(df,function(x) str_detect(x,"a"))` which will give you this -

   ```
     col1  col2     a
   ```

   [1,]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
   [2,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
   [3,] FALSE FALSE FALSE
2. Next you do `any(sapply(df,function(x) str_detect(x,"a")),TRUE)`
    - this is where things are going wrong. `any` is not being applied row wise and the output is a single boolean value. You have if apply the `any` function row wise to get what you want.

Comment: @macworthy oops silly typo thanks for pointing it out. Fixed it pls check