# If column contains string A and string B, then enter a value for that row

Tags: r

Let's say I have a data frame, df, that looks like:

```
A    B    C   
ABC  DEF  3.1
DEF  GHI  4.0
GHI  JKL  4.5
BXY  JDN  3.3
```

I want to insert into a new column, D, values (let's say Blue, Red, Green) if A, B, C meet certain criteria.

Something like this:

```
A    B    C    D 
ABC  DEF  3.1  Blue
DEF  GHI  4.0  Red
GHI  JKL  4.5  Green
BXY  JDN  3.3  Blue
```

So for example, if the character "B" is present in column A, "D" is present in column B, and C < 3.5, then insert "Blue" in a new column, D. All three criteria need to be met.

This is very similar to a previous question I found: [If Column Contains String then enter value for that row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39903376/if-column-contains-string-then-enter-value-for-that-row) which I've tried to modify without success.

I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you have lot of conditions to check `case_when` would be helpful.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(D = case_when(grepl('B', A) & grepl('D', B) & C < 3.5 ~ 'Blue', 
                       ...more..condition ~ 'another_value'))
```